# NGINX: set_by_lua doesn't work

Tags: variables, nginx, lua

I have NGINX running as a proxy service and want to set SSL key depending on the `$ENV` variable (in Docker Compose file).

I added to the `nginx.conf`:

```
env ENVKEY;
```

And then in the config file:

```
server {

    resolver 10.0.0.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 60s;

    server_name  _;

    listen 443;

    ssl on;

#    perl_set $envkey 'sub { return $ENV{"ENVKEY"}; }';
    set_by_lua $envkey 'return os.getenv("ENVKEY")';

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/jm-website-$envkey.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/jm-website-$envkey.key;
```

I also tried to use `perl_set` - but it can be used in the `location` only, but `ssl_certificate` - in the `http` or `server` blocks.

Using `set_by_lua` - I have an error:

> nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/nginx/ssl/jm-website-$envkey.crt")
>   failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or
>   directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/ssl/jm-website-$envkey.crt','r')
>   error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

Although variable present in the environment:

```
root@d0718b0a3361:/etc/nginx# echo $ENVKEY
dev
```

What I'm doing wrong here?
Maybe there is better approach?

Answer (score -2):

I do know that this is an old thread. I'm posting this for posterity's sake.

I was having the same problem as you were/are.

What is happening is that there's an order [to when the lua blocks gets executed](https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Directives/). `set_by_lua` happens right after the certificate is validated.

What you could do is either render you nginx.conf using a render engine of your choice (e.g.: python jinja) or you could write your own [ssl_certificate_by_lua_block](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/#ssl_certificate_by_lua_block) that reads from an environment variable. [Here is an exemple of an implementation using said block](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/ssl.md). You could also check [how Kong does it](https://github.com/Kong/kong/blob/59ef814e0f725cd9fd1c3cf38821debec68a99c4/kong/core/certificate.lua).

Hope it helps :)